# $scope.$watch in Controller not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Edit (18 Jul 13): As per your suggestion, I've altered the code a little bit, Code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pcwaci5oQ0ANIslPlPmd but it still is not working correctly. The example is a simple test to see how $watch works. I am setting a variable and defining a $watch on that variable and am then updating the watched variable twice. It appears that the $watch is only called once, but I expect it to be called 3 times (including the initial call, though I also wonder how to make that first call optional).

```
$scope.name = 'World'; //initial assignment
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.$watch('name', function(){
    $scope.count++;
});

$scope.name = 'Bob';//should increment the value to 2
$scope.name = 'Jane';//should increment the value to 3
```

Why is $scope.count equal to 1 after this code runs?

---

Original Request:
In this `plunker`, http://plnkr.co/edit/Pcwaci5oQ0ANIslPlPmd, I am setting a count variable, a name variable, and defining a `$watch` on `$scope` inside of the `controller`.

I am expecting the value of count to resolve ultimately to 1, but it remains unchanged from its initialization.

Comment: $scope.count =$scope.count+1; ++ cannot work with initilization either just use $scope.count++

Comment: Please include enough of your code to properly understand the question in the body of your question itself, not behind a link to plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that the `$scope` is only checked for changes when `$digest()` is called.  This happens implicitly when your controller function exits, so not matter how many times you change it inside the function, from outside the function it only appears to change once.  If you want to force the changes, you can make an explicit call to `$digest()`.  This is often done in testing scenarios, but is of limited utility in most regular controllers.

See the docs on [scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for more info, particularly the `$watch` and `$digest` sections. Under the `$watch` section, there is an example that mirrors what you are trying to do above.

```js
$scope.name = 'Bob';//should increment the value to 2
$scope.$digest()
$scope.name = 'Jane';//should increment the value to 3
$scope.$digest()
```

Answer (score 4):

++ after a variable means add one to the value on the right (after assignment)... interestingly this doesn't work exactly how I would expect either, but if you drop the assignment (stuff on the left) and just increment it works (since the ++ is really like $scope.count=$scope.count+1).  This is also true in "normal" javascript outside of angular:

```
var y=5;
y=y++;
console.log(y); //5
```

Apparently it must store the value of the right side, then increment the right side then assign the stored value to the left side.

```
$scope.count=0;
$scope.count++; //this results in 1
```

However

```
$scope.count=0;
$scope.count=$scope.count++; //this results in 0
```

Alternatively you could preincrement it

```
$scope.count=0;
$scope.count=++$scope.count; //this results in 1
```